# Option to check if first key of string has value

Tags: php

Im looking for a solution to check if a string have 0 or not.

My case is:

i have this code ean: 88125455454

in the system this code has 0 at the start, ex: 088125455454
But the barcode does not have the 0.
Another barcodes has the 0 first.

So i entered all codes in database with 0.

Now, what function is right to use in php to check if exist 0 first if not add 0.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/substr

Comment: does `ltrim` will do this ?

Comment: No, [`ltrim`](http://php.net/ltrim) is for *removing* characters, but you want to *add* them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
if (substr($code, 0, 1) != '0'){
 $code= '0'.$code;
}
```

and then store it